# Big binary tree as an induced subgraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, graph-minors

I believe this is true:

> Suppose $G$ is a graph. If $G$ has a subdivision of a large binary tree, prove that $G$ has an
>   induced subgraph which is a subdivision of a large binary tree or the line graph of a subdivision of a large binary tree.

However, I think it is very difficult to prove in general, so I was hoping to do it for the case when $G$ has bounded treewidth (or say really small treewidth). Any ideas for those cases? Thank you!

[EDIT: I initially forgot the word subdvision in the question]

[EDIT2: PROVED, someone can delete]

Comment: Why don't you just post a brief description of your answer, instead of requesting deletion?

Comment: Sure, i'll do that in a bit

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give a very brief sketch.

Find a large subdivided binary tree $T$ with branch vertices far apart and minimize its number of edges.
This should be possible by tweaking 'far apart' and 'large' in accordance with the tree width.

Every edge spanned by $T$ but not in $T$ lies in the neighbourhood of a branch vertex $v$ of $T$.
Case analysis gives desired structures locally:

- one edge in $N(v)$: it's the linegraph of a subdivided claw
- two edges in $N(v)$: remove $v$ it's a subdivided claw
- three edges in $N(v)$: remove $v$ it's the linegraph of a subdivided claw

Now you have large graph $T$ that is a mixture of a subdivided binary tree and a linegraph of a subdivided binary tree.
Since it is large enough you find branch vertices of the same type often enough.

Sorry, I had a longer answer that my pc forgot about. I'll elaborate if you have further question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question - I meant something else. You are of course right for what I initially wrote.

Comment: I think there is another counterexample for this version too:

Start with a triangle.

i) add an edge to every vertex of degree one.

ii) add a triangle to every vertex of degree 2.

repeat i) and ii) until your graph is large enough.

Basically, the graph looks like a binary tree, but every vertex is blown up to be a triangle.

Comment: Sorry, you start with a triangle and add an edge to every vertex of degree one?

Comment: Yeah, that needed to be 'two'. So you have a triangle, at every vertex you add an edge to some new vertex. Now you have a triangle, plus three leaves. For every vertex of degree one (the three new vertices) you add one triangle and identify one vertex of the first triangle with the first leaf, one vertex of the second triangle with the second leaf. Same for 'three'.

Comment: that's nice; can we say something about the induced subgraphs however? it pretty much looks like there's no other bad graphs

Comment: yes i think so. you get a subdivision of a large binary tree that is mostly induced, only at a vertex of degree 3 you have 0 - 3 edges in its neighbourhood.

Comment: can you post an answer with a proof? :)

Comment: actually: the line graph of your example is a subdivision of a binary tree! so it's not really a counterexample

Comment: I can't follow. The line graph of any graph with some degree $\ge 3$ vertex, cannot be a subdivision of a binary tree as it contains a cycle, right?

Comment: can you please elaborate on your choice of $T$? what does far apart mean more precisely? thanks in advance